# Pro and cons between Bayesian structural time series (BSTS) vs difference-in-differences?

Tags: causality, hierarchical-bayesian, difference-in-difference, causalimpact, bsts

Google's [paper](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub41854) markets BSTS's benefits over DID such that

> "In contrast to classical difference-in-differences schemes,
>   state-space models make it possible to (i) infer the temporal
>   evolution of attributable impact, (ii) incorporate empirical priors on
>   the parameters in a fully Bayesian treatment, and (iii) flexibly
>   accommodate multiple sources of variation, including the time-varying
>   influence of contemporaneous covariates, i.e., synthetic controls."

What are other pro-and-cons of the methods?

Comment: It depends on the context: Pros and cons when considering these techniques in order to do what? Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @tinaw generally interested.